# How to generate random numbers between 0 and 1 in bash

Tags: bash, shell, random

I'm trying to infer how to generate two random numbers as input values for parameters of `readproportion`, `updateproportion` in a way that sum of these parameters should equal 1, in the following bash command.

```
$ ./bin/ycsb run basic -P workloads/workloada -p readproportion=0.50 -p updateproportion=0.50
```

Please help with your suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: If the sum of two numbers (`a` and `b`) are predetermined, you only need to generate a random value for the first one (`a`), since `b` will always be `1 - a`

Comment: Bash is a bad tool for this. Why not use a general purpose programming language? For example, `ruby -r 'securerandom' -e 'puts SecureRandom.random_number'` and then *you* handle what amounts to a knapsack problem?

Comment: @CodeGnome I posted my solution where I used python random number generator function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can remember ${RANDOM} generates integers in the interval 0 - 32767. So, I guess, you might want to try something like this to generate random values in [0,1]:

```
bc -l <<< "scale=4 ; ${RANDOM}/32767"
```

Comment: for me this gives same every time

Comment: Use this to get a different result every time: `echo "scale=4 ; ${RANDOM}/32767" | bc -l`

Answer (score 2):

```
$ arr=( $(awk 'BEGIN{srand(); r=rand(); print r, 1-r}') )
$ echo "${arr[0]}"
0.661624
$ echo "${arr[1]}"
0.338376

$ arr=( $(awk 'BEGIN{srand(); r=rand(); printf "%.2f %.2f\n", r, 1-r}') )
$ echo "${arr[0]}"
0.74
$ echo "${arr[1]}"
0.26
```

`srand()` will only update the seed once per second but as long as you don't need to call the script more frequently than once per second it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a super simple way to do it:

```
echo 0."$RANDOM"
```

^^ DO NOT USE AND READ BELOW ^^

## Edit:

I cannot read:

```
$ rnum=$((RANDOM%10000+1))
$ echo "scale=4; $rnum/10000" | bc
.8748
$ echo "scale=4; 1-$rnum/10000" | bc
.1252
```

## Edit 2:

As pointed out the first iteration of this is terrible. Once I read the issue entirely and tried to do some simple maths with the "number". I realized that this is super broken. You can read more at:

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html
- and -
https://www.shell-tips.com/2010/06/14/performing-math-calculation-in-bash/

Comment: Edit was for quoting the variable.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I create two random numbers with defined condition and assign them into two variables?

Comment: This has a very bad distribution!

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I hadn't used $RANDOM or bc before I am just on here to try to lean the bash things and research stuff as I go:

Comment: Those were the two references that I used to learn about $RANDOM and bc.

Answer (score 1):

With idea from Robert J:

```
RANDOM=$$                      # Reseed using script's PID
r1=$((${RANDOM}%98+1))
r2=$((100-$r1))
printf -v r1 "0.%.2d" $r1
printf -v r2 "0.%.2d" $r2
echo "$r1 $r2"
```

Output (e.g.):

```
0.66 0.34
0.01 0.99
0.42 0.58
0.33 0.67
0.22 0.78
0.33 0.67
0.65 0.35
0.77 0.23
0.71 0.29
```

Comment: Very bad distribution too. `:(`.

Comment: I hope you're aware that 0.5 and 0.95 do not actually add up to 1. :-)

Comment: @ruakh: Thank you for this hint! I fixed this bug.

Comment: What if the script's PID is constant?

Answer (score 1):

This is "wasteful" (it just throws away characters until `/dev/urandom` happens to spit out enough ascii `0` to `9`s), but it is securely pseudorandom:

```
rand_frac() { echo -n 0.; LANG=C tr -dc 0-9 </dev/urandom | head -c12; }
```

Then, you can

```
$ echo The random number is.... $(rand_frac)
The random number is.... 0.413856349581
```

`LANG=C` is there to prevent `tr` from choking on bad UTF-8 sequences from `/dev/urandom`. `-dc` means `d`elete the `c`ompliment of the subsequent character class (so, delete everything except `0-9`).

You can change the `0-9` to generate arbitrary character classes, or adjust `head -c 12` to something else, which can be useful for making passwords.

Answer (score 1):

This works nice

```sh
$ bc -l <<< "scale=16; $(od -t u2 -An -N2 /dev/random)/(2 ^ 16)"
.2792053222656250
```